# "attempt to call a nil value (global 'include')"

Tags: lua, add-on, garrys-mod

i have this code :

```
include("autorun/sh_myaddon.lua")
local myName = "Jakub"
local age = 999
print(myName)
print(age)
```

When i pressed f7 this showned up :

```
lua: ...rrysmod\addons\myaddon\lua\autorun\server\sv_myaddon.lua:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'include')
stack traceback:
    ...rrysmod\addons\myaddon\lua\autorun\server\sv_myaddon.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I Tried searching but i found nothing :(

Comment: That error message looks like it's being given by stand-alone Lua. "include" seems to be a Lua extension from Garry's Mod, so it will fail like this if you aren't running it through Garry's Mod. Presumably "F7" is some auto-run feature of your IDE, and it isn't set up to run your code via Garry's Mod (if that is even possible).